# Play with fragments in onTabSelected

Tags: android, android-fragments

**Dears,**

I searched for this issue for more than a day but with no luck. 
I implement exactly the code posted here:

[Adding Navigation Tabs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs)

My code for onTabSelected look like:

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // Check if the fragment is already initialized
        if (mFragment == null) {
            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(R.id.alert_fragment_container, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
            ft.attach(mFragment);
        }

        // prepare adapter for ExpandableListView

        Log.i("After Adapter Created", "Passed");

        final ExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter = new AlertsAdapter(
                mActivity, myAlerts, violations);

        Log.i("After Adapter Initialized", "Passed");

       ((MyCustomFragment)mFragment).violations.setAdapter(expListAdapter);
    }
```

The code is working fine till last line, where I need to set the adapter for public static list initialized in `MyCustomFragment` in `onCreateView`, here my code for fragment:

```
public class MyCustomFragment extends Fragment {

    public MyCustomFragment() {
    }

    public static ExpandableListView violations; 

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alerts_poi, container, false);

        violations = (ExpandableListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.POIAlertList);

        Log.i("onCreateView POI", "Called");

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

It give Null pointer error. With my debugging logs, I notice that this log `Log.i("onCreateView POI", "Called");` appears after this `Log.i("After Adapter Initialized", "Passed");`. This means that I'm trying to set the adapter for a fragment isn't initialized yet.

This is the exact problem I'm face, I need to fed the `ExpandableListView` with data based on Tab selection in `onTabSelected`.

What I'm doing wrong? What is the best solution?

Regards,

Comment: "Dears"? +1 just in case you're a Programming Grandmother

Comment: Have a look @ this [Tablayout.OnTabSelectedListener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17210674/how-to-get-which-fragment-has-been-selected/35127695#35127695) for latest updates.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need a **ViewPager**, I just implemented a navigation tabs few days ago, here is my code, it navigates between 4 fragments:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener{
private ActionBar actionBar;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
private AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    actionBar=getActionBar();
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.icon1).setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.icon2).setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.icon3).setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.icon4).setTabListener(this));     
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

And here is the adapter:

```
public class AppSectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
public AppSectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    switch (i) {
        case 0:
            return new Fragment1();
        case 1:
            return new Fragment2();
        case 2:
            return new Fragment3();
        case 3: 
            return new Fragment4();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 4;
}

}
```

Comment: Where I can place code for preparing and setting the Adapter? Also, is there any solution rather than this one? In case case I will apply the solution, I need to change many things in my structure. Why my way is wrong?

Comment: You don't need to change many things, the adapter is initialized in the MainActivity, and I don't know what dose your main activity look like, so it hard to figure out what's wrong with your code, in the MainActivity above, there is also a onTabSelected() method, I also followed the same tutorial as you, hopefully you can find the bug by comparing the code above with your one

Comment: I convert my code to new activity using `ViewPager`. It works fine for the second, third and fourth tab. The first one still give me Null pointer. I placed the code of initializing the adapter in `onPageSelected(int position)` of `ViewPager` listener. I tried to force listener to be call `onPageSelected(int position)` for the first position = 0 using `pageChangeListener.onPageSelected(0);` with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look @ this [Tablayout.onTabselected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17210674/how-to-get-which-fragment-has-been-selected/35127695#35127695) for latest API updates. ActionBar.TabListener is a old implementation.