# Android Tablayout at current tab position show next tab Toast and Logs

Tags: android, android-fragments, material-design, android-tablayout

During Tablayout practices i am follow this code from [link](https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/). but problem is while i am current tab show next tab Toast and Log-cat.Here is my code

ScrollableTabsActivity.java

```
package info.androidhive.materialtabs.activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import info.androidhive.materialtabs.R;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.EightFragment;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.FiveFragment;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.FourFragment;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.NineFragment;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.OneFragment;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.SevenFragment;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.SixFragment;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.TenFragment;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.ThreeFragment;
import info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.TwoFragment;

public class ScrollableTabsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrollable_tabs);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new 
    ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
    adapter.addFrag(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
    adapter.addFrag(new FourFragment(), "FOUR");
    adapter.addFrag(new FiveFragment(), "FIVE");
    adapter.addFrag(new SixFragment(), "SIX");
    adapter.addFrag(new SevenFragment(), "SEVEN");
    adapter.addFrag(new EightFragment(), "EIGHT");
    adapter.addFrag(new NineFragment(), "NINE");
    adapter.addFrag(new TenFragment(), "TEN");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
}
```

activity_scrollable_tabs.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="scrollable"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

OneFragment.java

```
package info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import info.androidhive.materialtabs.R;


public class OneFragment extends Fragment{

public OneFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, container, false);
}

}
```

fragment_one.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="info.androidhive.materialtabs.fragments.OneFragment">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/one"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Second and Third fragment code is same as mention as Tab 1 code. i just add following code at third Tab code `onCreateView` method

```
Toast.makeText(getContext(), "3 fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: 3 fragment ");
```

i am getting following output

[image: Output]

as you can show fragment 3 Toast come at second fragment i also notice third fragment log-cat also come at second fragment. i don't know what wrong happen but i notice all time at my current Tab position upcoming Tab Toast and log-cat
show and it will happen at any position at tablayout tab. i am also try other tutorials and other method for create scrollable Tablayout but in all practices i am getting same type of problem. please help me to solve problem i just want my upcoming fragment can't start proceeding until i was visit.at the end sorry for bed formatting i am newbies.

Comment: Second and Third fragment code is same as mention as Tab 1 code. i just add following code at third Tab code onCreateView method

Toast.makeText(getContext(), "3 fragment", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView: 3 fragment ");

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/19027096/6834114

Answer (score 1):

You can check the current selected tab

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
       // Show your toast here
    }
}
```

You can use this method to know the currently displayed tab

Comment: i Know about how getting right tab position  but my concern about this practices is why i am getting my upcoming tab data from current tab.  
and how to stop proceeding Upcoming tab until i was not visited at this tab

Comment: You cannot stop that instead the code you are calling in onCreateView() you can shift to this method to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

The `FragmentPagerAdapter` creates the instance of the next fragment, before it gets used. Part of the lifecycle of the Fragment is called, before the Fragment is attached to the window and is visible.
Some info from Android docs about [FragmentPagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html) says:

> Implementation of PagerAdapter that represents each page as a Fragment that is persistently kept in the fragment manager as long as the user can return to the page.
>
> The fragment of each page the user visits will be kept in memory, though its view hierarchy may be destroyed when not visible.

This is not a sufficient info, but basically it says, that the methods `onCreateView()` and `onDestroyView()` are not directly connected with the visibility of the Fragment to the user, so better think about placing your code in `onResume()` for example or use `viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener()` to get informed about the changing of pages.

Comment: i Know about `viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener()` and `tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener()` i am getting right tab position using this method  but my concern about this practices is why i am getting my upcoming tab data from current tab.

Comment: and how to stop proceeding Upcoming tab until i was not visited at this tab

Comment: @Basit, as I have said the next Fragment(s) are created, before they get visible, so onCreateView() is called earlier, while you're still on a previous tab.